# Search & Destroy Rouge Process in OSX

Tags: macos, process

**INFO:** I installed SymformSync the other day, a distributed cloud storage system, but deleted it again the same day. (I like the idea, but it's not suitable for someone on a laptop like me.) However, there's a process symformsync that keeps popping up and consuming pretty heavily on the CPU.  I deleted the application, but this process still keeps popping up!  Needless to say, I don't appreciate not having control over the processes on my own CPU!

**Q:** How do I find this process that keeps starting up by itself, and how do I delete it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer from Symform:

Thank you for contacting Symform support.  I understand that you are needing the instructions to remove Symform from your Mac.

Here is the information:

1. Access the Terminal program on your Mac, by going to the search tool in the upper right-hand corner, and entering in Terminal.
2. Once Terminal is open, enter in the following command, depending on what you want to do:

Normal uninstall will only stop the services and remove the software. It will leave the service configuration and log files in place.

sudo /Library/Application\ Support/Symform/scripts/uninstall

To completely remove all aspects of the Symform software, configuration, and logs, a purging operation is available as well. This will remove any synchronization and contribution supporting files and directories too.

sudo /Library/Application\ Support/Symform/scripts/uninstall --purge

1. You will need to enter in your Mac password when running either of these commands.

Comment: This should absolutely be on the FAQ. I too installed Symform on my laptop, realized it wasn't right for a laptop, and was stuck trying to get rid of it.